# Does there exist a good generic production-level fine-tuning script for transformer models?

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers

Does there exist a generic script for fine-tuning generative language (transformer) models?
It could be based on a library that supports loading many different models (for example, HuggingFace).

I can find many tutorials online on some Jupyter or Colab notebooks.
But for fine-tuning (transfer learning) task it does not seem you need any custom code. You basically only need a set of text files specifying inputs and outputs and some configuration parameters which can be specified via command line or in a config file. The base pretrained model name can itself be a parameter.

While some tutorials are good, it is not always obvious how much tested they are.
It seems that many generic parts (reading the data, saving the model, etc) would better be reused rather than coded again and again (imperfectly) by each different user.

I am interested in a proper script that has been well tested in production,
has dependencies properly specified, and can be used to fine tune
on various architectures (CPU, various GPU architectures, multiple GPUs, TPU) and various data scales,
and does not require logging in to any specific paid platforms and
preferably with minimal package dependencies.

The transformers library has something similar, but the dependencies are out of date and the requirements do not specify exact versions: https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/tree/main/examples/research_projects/seq2seq-distillation. I think in the area of image processing, Tensorflow [Transfer Learning](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning) project used to have such scripts, but now it seems to have moved to just a python tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that more up-to-date scripts are available in [huggingface/transformers](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers) github repository and in the `examples` directory:

- [examples/pytorch](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/tree/main/examples/pytorch)
- [examples/flax](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/tree/main/examples/flax)
- [examples/tensorflow](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/tree/main/examples/tensorflow)

However for some backends (for example, pytorch) the scripts seem to be better tested and more complete than for others (for example, tensorflow).